# How to count consecutive string values of one column grouped by column values of another in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, data-structures

I have the following dataframe:

```
|Levels|Labels|Confidence|
|----------------------------
|0.    | Hands |  0.8
|0     |Leg    |  0.7    
|0     |Eye.   | 0.9
|1     |Ear    |0.9
|1     |Eye.   |0.8
|2     |Hands  |0.9
|2     |Eye.   |0.8
|3.    |Eye.   |0.8
:
:
:
```

I want to check if any of my labels are consecutively present in my levels (0,1,2,3,4,5..)and for how many consecutive levels (count of such consecutive levels for each of my bodyparts). Here is my example dataset, you can see that the label "Eye" is consecutively present for 4 levels, "Hands" for 1..etc.

There is a similar question here :
[How to find the count of consecutive same string values in a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53383208/how-to-find-the-count-of-consecutive-same-string-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe)
Modifying this solution there did not work for me. I also tried to convert this into a NumPy array which also did not work.

Could you take a look at this?

Comment: Are you considering only the occurrences starting at lvl 0? Or do you want to look at the longest consecutive occurrence starting at any level?

Comment: @Mark at any level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Just define custom aggregating function.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'lvl': [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4],
    'label': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c'],
    'confidence': [0.1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 0.8]
})


agg_func = {
    'lvl': [('length', lambda x: x.ne((x+1).shift()).cumsum().value_counts().max())]
}

result = df.groupby('label').agg(agg_func)
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)

print(result)
```

```
       length
label        
a           4
b           2
c           3
```

Comment: this is working. Thank you very much, could you please explain a bit about agg_func()?

Comment: Is there a way to get a list of labels(say top 3 or n) in the consecutive data frame "result". What I want is to know which set of labels occurs most consecutively together? Would you know how to do that?