# Finding top 3 row values that occurs together in consecutive columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, numpy

I have the following dataframe:

```
|Levels|Labels|Confidence|
|----------------------------
|0.    |Hands |  0.8
|0     |Leg    |  0.7    
|0     |Eye.   | 0.9
|1     |Ear    |0.9
|1     |Eye.   |0.8
|2     |Hands  |0.9
|2     |Eye.   |0.8
|3.    |Eye.   |0.8
|3.    |Hands. |0.8
|3     |Ear|.  |0.9
|4.    |Eye.   |0.7
|5     |Hands. |0.7
|6.    |Ear.   |0.8

:
:
```

Say my list of labels is :

```
labels= ['Ear','Hands','Eyes','Leg','Finger','Lips']
```

I want to write a function that returns a set of most(some number n, say top three) consecutively occurring lables. I don't know how to approach this one.

Here my expected outcome for the top3 consecutively occurring ones will be Top 3 =[ 'Hands', 'Eye', 'Ear']

I had sometime back posted a question on finding consecutively occurring labels here:
here:[How to count consecutive string values of one column grouped by column values of another in a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090994/how-to-count-consecutive-string-values-of-one-column-grouped-by-column-values-of)

Comment: What's your expected output for the example you posted? It's not quite clear to me what you want to do.

Comment: Top 3 =[ 'Hands','Eye','Ear']

Comment: @mcsoini edited. It is easier with an example

Comment: Do you mean the three most **frequent** ones?

Comment: @sai what I want is to find from my list of labels which ones(which three/which N)  occur most consecutively together.

Comment: what's your definition of consecutive? I don't ever see any consecutive value of 'Hands',  where definition I'm using is appears in consecutive rows

Comment: @RobRaymond consecutive levels.{Level:0,1,2 are consecutive, levels:2,3,4,5,6 are consecutive)

Comment: @amarykya_ishtmella IIUC, from your original question, if you use result as in the accepted answer, then doing something like `result.sort_values('length', ascending=False).index[:3]` and you can change 3 by any number your want, it should work