# Find if there are consecutive 3 or more rows present in a dataframe based on values of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a list of

```
labels= ['Ear','Hands','Eyes','Leg','Finger','Lips']
```

I have the following dataframe:

```
|Frames|Labels|Confidence|
|----------------------------
|0     |Hands  |  0.8
|0     |Leg    |  0.7    
|0     |Eye    |  0.9
|1     |Ear    |  0.9
|1     |Eye    |  0.8
|2     |Hands  |  0.9
|2     |Eye    |  0.8
|3.    |Eye    |  0.8
|3.    |Hands  |  0.8
|3     |Ear    |  0.9
|4     |Eye    |  0.7
|4     |Hands  |  0.8
|5     |Hands  |  0.7
|5     |Ear    |  0.9
|5     |Eye    |  0.9
|6     |Ear    |  0.8
|6
:
:
```

I want to check if there are any consecutive 3 or more (or 'N') frames(eg:1,2,3.. or 3,4,5,6.. basically frames one after the other) which has detected atleast 2 same labels from the list of labels.( The labels name do not matter as long as they are consequitively detected)

Here, Hands and eyes are deteced consequently for more than 3 frames.
So, I want to return the number of the frames (1,2,3,4,5) and the labels that are detected which here is (Hands,Eyes)

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Is `Ear` different from `Ear.`?

Comment: @QuangHoang It's a typo.Happens when you make table. I will change it

Comment: Why do you post repeat question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66090994/how-to-count-consecutive-string-values-of-one-column-grouped-by-column-values-of

Comment: @Epsi95 they are two different questions. Please read the questions.

Comment: From the first glance, they're pretty much the same question. You should explain how different they are AND/OR how the solution to the previous question does not solve this question.

Comment: @Epsi95 oh, last time you had tried to answer it, but you had a different username I guess.

Comment: @QuangHoang because here I am specifying the number of elements (2) from the list I want so that the frames can be considered to be consecutive.The previous solution returned the number of levels.(like: 456-ear,400-hand..for each body parts) but not the exact frame numbers that were consecutive( 30,31,32....60)

Comment: It would help a lot if you cleaned up your question. For example, you have "Eyes" in the `labels` list but "Eye" in the dataframe, and extra periods in the example table. If you're asking for help, please invest the time to make it easy for people to work on it. Separately, it's also not clear (to me, at least) exactly what you want, so a second example output might help.